# Javascript execution engine with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry for the stupid question and the indentation of the code source below. I am completely new to coding. Could someone help me understand why I need to click on the submit button twice to see the second correct answer turn green as per the code below? Worse, when I insert an 'alert' method into the script, the first correct answer turns green only after I click on the 'OK' of the alert window.

Thank you very much

Ehoussoud

```js
function check() {
  var cans = document.getElementsByClassName('correct');
  for (i = 0; i < cans.length; i++) {
    cans[i].className = "cool";
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.cool {
  color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Premier League 2017/18 Quiz</h1>

  <form>

    <p>Q1.Which of the three championship teams were promoted to the premier league?
    </p><br>

    <div class="correct"> <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A">Wolves,Cardiff,Fulham </div>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="B">Wolves,Middlesbrough,Aston Villa
    </br>


    <p>Q2.Which player made the most assists?<br></p>

    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="A">David Silva</br>
    <div class="correct"><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="B">Kevin De Bruyne
    </div>
    </br>

    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="check()">

  </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the first iteration you are renaming one the elements with class `correct`. So, it you had two elements with this class (How is the case) in the second iteration `cans[i]` (i = 1) will not exists because `cans` just have one element. So for that i access `cans[0]` because it's all going to exists.

```js
function check() {
  var cans = document.getElementsByClassName('correct');
  var quantity = cans.length;
  for (i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    cans[0].className = "cool";
  }

}
```

```css
form {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.cool {
  color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Premier League 2017/18 Quiz</h1>

  <form>

    <p>Q1.Which of the three championship teams were promoted to the premier league?
    </p><br>

    <div class="correct"> <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A">Wolves,Cardiff,Fulham </div>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="B">Wolves,Middlesbrough,Aston Villa
    </br>


    <p>Q2.Which player made the most assists?<br></p>

    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="A">David Silva</br>
    <div class="correct"><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="B">Kevin De Bruyne
    </div>
    </br>

    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="check()">

  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Michael Montero, I appreciate your help. It works fine. But why do you use this cans[0].className = "cool" instead of cans[i].className = "cool" to iterate the loop?

Comment: Sorry to bother @MichaelMontero, aren't cans[0]="Wolves, Cardiff, Fulham" and cans[1]="Kevin De Bruyne"? How do both elements of the can[ ] array become green if the loop does not iterate?

Comment: Very very helpful though I have learnt a lot here, I need to get my head around the number of elements with the class ‘correct’ is adjusted during the iteration process. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery could save you some time when you are working with multiple elements with the same id/class. You were using `element.className = "class-name";` You should use `element.classList.add("class-name");` like so:

```
function check(){
    var cans=document.getElementsByClassName('correct');
    for(i=0;i<cans.length;i++){
        cans[i].classList.add("cool"); 
    }         
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, Oriont. It works fine! You aced it!